# django-rest-auth authentication not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I wanted a simple api authentication route using `django-rest-framework` and 'django-rest-auth`. The register part is working fine as confirmed by the default django admin console and i can also see the users. Unluckily the api authentication keeps on returning me with error

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

Currently the configuration that i have for my `allauth` is as follows

```
# all-auth configuration
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD="email"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED=False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION="none"
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE=False

# CORS Configuration
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
```

I am unsure what part I am missing. Please guide me in the right direction. There are no errors and the response code is 400. The credentials are correct as verified from django admin panel. Thanks in advance

#### Update

The problem is somewhat with email. I commented the configuration out and tried to generate a token with username and password. That works without any error.

Comment: Have you checked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347200/django-rest-http-400-error-on-getting-token-authentication-view)?

Comment: @Fian  just checked all of the conditions are true as mentioned at that answer.

Comment: Do you use valid email? You can try to debug it [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L71).

Comment: same problem here, any solution found?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add these backends to settings.py file

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```